# Inserir valor na Tabela Y para todas ID existente da Tabela X

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada `CONTAS` com uma coluna `account_id`.

[image: Tabela contas]

Tenho outra tabela chamada `PREMIO` com colunas `account_id`, `id_premio` e `itemqtd`

[image: Tabela premio]

Eu queria um comando onde eu inseri-se o `id_premio` e `itemqtd` mas para a coluna chamada `account_id` ele inserir todas `account_id` da tabela `CONTAS` pois quero dar o mesmo Premio e quantidade para todas as contas registradas até aquele momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso aqui deve resolver o seu problema

```
insert into premio(contas_id, id_premio, qtd_premio)
select contas_id, 01, 1500 from contas
```

Explicando: Será feito um `select` em todos os dados da tabela `CONTAS` trazendo o campo `contas_id`, o código do prêmio (01) e a quantidade do prêmio (1500) e os mesmo serão incluídos na tabela prêmio.

Modifique os valores exemplos de acordo com sua necessidade.

Obs.: Tome cuidado com as chaves primárias, se o campo `id_premio` for a chave primária da tabela `PREMIO` você terá que ver como irá tratar corretamente.

**EDITADO**

O insert ficaria desta forma

```
insert into entregador(account_id, id_premio, itemqtd)
select account_id, 1, 13 from login
```

Comment: Opa obrigado, mas obtive o seguinte erro:
#1054 - Coluna 'contas_id' desconhecida em 'field list'

o nome da coluna está correto e existe na tabela, porém contas_id é chave primaria da tabela CONTAS já id_premio não é chave primaria

Comment: Tem algo estranho então na estrutura que tu passou... Não tem como você editar sua resposta e por uma imagem da estrutura de cada tabela?

Comment: Usei nomes ficticios para poder explicar mas vou passar como está:
Tabela de contas ( chamada login ) - http://prntscr.com/ow8jfa
Tabela premios ( chamada entregador ) - http://prntscr.com/ow8kse

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta, é estranho ocorrer esse erro citado por você se o campo existe...

Comment: Muitíssimo Obrigado cara pela sua atenção  ajuda, funcionou do jeito que eu precisava! 
Ps: a primeira tentativa eu digitei um caractere errado e não vi. rs

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONTAS_ID into PREMIO from CONTAS
```

Quando usamos INTO jogamos todos resultados para a tabela informada.

Comment: ele retorna um erro LIMIT 0, 25 e nessa linha onde coloco  ( ID_PREMIO ) e ( QTD_PREMIO )  numérico tipo 444 e 1